# Dogs Stuff or Dog Stuff

Tags: grammar

I'm going to open an online store, and weirdly, i'm stuck at naming my collections. Every collection has"name + stuff" in it.

Should it be Dogs Stuff or Dog Stuff?
Same goes for the Cat. Should it be Cats Stuff or Cat Stuff?

Thanks

Comment: *Dog stuff* sounds like something I might step in. Are you sure this title is a good idea?

Comment: What's your opinion? is it a bad idea to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for naming advice.

Comment: How about *Stuff for Dogs*?

Comment: *Stuff* near *dog* (or *cat*) brings wrong informal connotations on either side.  "Dog stuff" implies outputs other users have noted.  "Stuff for dogs" etc. connotes the *verb* "stuff", i.e. stuffing for either a stuffed toy animal, or an actual stuffed animal (taxidermy), or worse something like a Thanksgiving Turkey.

Answer (score 2):

If you go with **Dogs' Stuff** you're going to need an apostrophe after **Dogs**.

**Dog Stuff** sounds a tad simpler and catchier. The only problem is it could be confused with canine waste product :-)

Comment: Yes, and *Dog Stuff* sounds like a command to eat quickly, especially if a comma is inserted between the words: *Dog, sit! Dog, roll over. Good dog. Here's some food for you. Dog, stuff!*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter either way, it's acceptable as "Dog Stuff" as in "stuff for a dog" or the possessive/plural/plural possessive version "Dogs Stuff".

I'd suggest looking at alternative words for "stuff" though, it reads unprofessional and boring.